# What happened to Daniel Jackson's allergies?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

Both in the Stargate movie and early on in Stargate SG1, Daniel Jackson's allergies are used frequently in the plot (for example, slowing down the party in the movie and as a method of communication during Children of the Gods). His allergies would act up every time he traveled through the gate (or drastically changed environments).

This seems to have just vanished and now Daniel Jackson is travelling around with no issues. What happened to Daniel Jackson's allergies?

Comment: Presumably they became too tedious for the showrunner to want care about any more.

Comment: He started taking anti-histamines. There's an episode where everyone is regressed into a neanderthal but he's immune because of his allergy medication.

Comment: His allergies were cured after his ascension.

Comment: @makeminefreedom - that only happens in season 4? 5?  And he still has to wear glasses afterwards, anyways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### He takes anti-allergy medication.

This was specifically referenced in a ([deleted](https://josephmallozzi.wordpress.com/2011/06/14/june-14-2011-ripple-effect-the-deleted-scenes/)) scene for the episode "[Ripple Effect](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Ripple_Effect)"

> **INT. INTERROGATION ROOM #2 — DAY**
>
> Green Mitchell is seated across the table from Desert Camo Daniel. A
>   glass of water and a pill dispenser sit in front of Desert Camo
>   Daniel.
>
> **DESERT CAMO DANIEL:** *So how do we get back to our reality?*
>
> **GREEN MITCHELL:** *We don’t know yet, but we’re working on it. In the
>   meantime, I’d like to ask you a few questions.*
>
> Desert Camo Daniel nods. Green Mitchell turns on the tape recorder
>   sitting on the table. **Desert Camo Daniel opens up the pill dispenser,
>   pops a couple, and washes them down. Off Green Mitchell’s look –**
>
> **DESERT CAMO DANIEL:** **Antihistamines. I have terrible allergies.**
>
> Green Mitchell nods, moves on –

and as Austin has pointed out in his comment above, this was also confirmed within "[The Broca Divide](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/1.05_%22The_Broca_Divide%22_Transcript)"

> **FRAISER**: *Because only some of them have this low histamine level which means there is probably a-a naturally occurring antihistamine in
>   their diets. The ones who don't eat it eventually contract the
>   organism. Which is what gave me an idea. **I checked the files; both
>   Dr. Jackson and I have acute rhinitis caused by severe allergies.***
>
> [O'Neill looks at Teal'c.]
>
> **TEAL'C:** *Explain.*
>
> **FRAISER:** ***I take strong antihistamines every day, so did Dr. Jackson.*** I have no histamine for the microbe to feed on. Just like
>   the Untouched, the organism starves in my body.